# How to apply separate opacity masks to different fills of on object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, fill, appearance

I'm using Ai and I'm trying to make an object -suppose a simple rectangle- with two different fill colors. One color is above and would be textured by an opacity mask so the second color would be seen through the first color. I can achieve a similar result by placing another rectangle with the desired color underneath the first one, and simply apply my texture to the top rectangle so the second color -or the second rectangle- would be seen underneath it.
But I'm wondered if there is a way to have this result with only one object? I've tried to do it by applying opacity mask to different fills of my rectangle but whenever I add an opacity mask to only one fill, it will automatically be applied to all the object and its fills, I don't know why it does happen since in the Appearance panel we should be able to add different effects and opacity masks to separate fills, but it looks like it's useless, applying one opacity mask to one fill would make it applied to all the fills and the object overall.
Any advice?[image]

I want to achieve something like this. The pink fill would be seen underneath the blue textured fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can't

Illustrator masks - Opacity *or* Clipping - are per-object and not "per appearance attribute".

An object either does or does not have a mask. You can not apply a mask, of any type, to individual fills or strokes in the Appearance Panel.

I don't understand why using 2 objects is a problem.. the blue texture and a pink rectangle behind it. Merely **group** the two objects if you wish for them to remain together.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm gonna make a really detailed artwork  with over 100 really detailed and textured rather smaller objects in it. So I thought if I can somehow manage to have texture and background in each object separately, it would reduce the number of objects thus making the management easier. I think I just got it wrong and thought it's possible cause I saw we have the option to add masks to each different appearance in the appearance panel. Maybe Adobe can remove this kinda useless feature in future Ai versions. XD

Comment: You *can* apply one opacity mask to a group of objects.

Comment: It's a great advice too :) I'd probably get to use it in future but for now I can't, because their textures are mostly different from each other.